# Finding a consistent estimator mathematically

Tags: self-study, variance, expected-value, estimators

This is my first post on this website so hopefully everything will go smoothly.

Let me first ask the question, then go over my problem.

Q: Suppose that we are given $({X_{1i},X_{2i}})$ which is a random sample from the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$. Assume that:

$$Var(X_1X_2-X_1e^{X_2})< infinity$$
We would like to estimate the following:

$$ \theta = E[(X_1X_2-X_1e^{X_2})]$$

I need to find a consistent estimator for the above estimate. Now I know what consistency of an estimator is. It means that as the sample size grows, the estimator gives a value closer and closer to the population estimate. Now what I do not know is HOW to actually come up with a consistent estimator mathematically.

Help on that front would be super appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since you are estimating an expectation for an i.i.d. sample of a  r.v., you can use the method of moments to estimate its mean. And since you know the r.v. has finite variance, the strong law of great numbers can be used to demonstrate its consistency.

Comment: Excuse me, it's the law of large numbers, I did a bad translation from spanish.